# String to timestamp conversion

Tags: ms-access

I have a table where date is given as string function as highlighted in orange colour and would like to convert in to timestamp field as highlighted in yellow in table attached. Would anyone please help me how to use the function and convert it into timestamp column in access?

[image]

Thanking you.

Comment: Post data as text instead of picture so that we can copy.

Comment: Please tag only a single RDBMS unless there is something specific in your question that requires both. Are you using SQL Server or MS Access?

Comment: Hi Dale, Sorry for not accepting for any of answers. I am sorry for that. I am using access database and would like to get a converted datetimestamp column.

Comment: DataSet SampleID TimeStamp
AMC MF1 04H 201231NS 31-12-20 4:00
AMC MF1 04H 210101NS 01-01-21 4:00
AMC MF1 04H 210102NS 02-01-21 4:00
AMC MF1 04H 210103NS 03-01-21 4:00
AMC MF1 04H 210104NS 04-01-21 4:00
AMC MF1 04H 210105NS 05-01-21 4:00
AMC MF1 04H 210106NS 06-01-21 4:00
AMC MF1 04H 210107NS 07-01-21 4:00
AMC MF1 04H 210108NS 08-01-21 4:00
AMC MF1 04H 210109NS 09-01-21 4:00                                                                                        I want to convert Sample ID column into Timestamp Datetime column using access. I don't know how to upload xls file

Answer (score 2):

It can be reduced to:

```
Timestamp = CDate(Format([SampleID], "!@@-@@-@@@@") & Str(Val([SampleID])) & ":0")
```

Example:

```
[SampleID] = "13H 11122017"
-> 2017-12-11 13:00:00
```

Comment: Great, I like that!

Comment: Hi Gustav, I am trying using this but it gives me an error. If i use another column and use this function, would i get the desired result. it is giving me an error.  I am trying ConvertedDateTime: CDate(Format([SampleID], "!@@-@@-@@@@") & Str(Val([SampleID])) & ":0")

Comment: We only have the picture of your sample data, so hard to tell. Do you have _Null_ values, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Try below query-

```
SELECT format(dateserial(right(t.SampleID,4),left(right(t.SampleID,6),2),left(right(t.SampleID,8),2)) + TimeSerial(left(t.SampleID,2),0,0),"dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm") AS ConvertedDateTime FROM Table1 as t;
```

> ***Edit:*** If you want to store converted `Date/Time` to table column then you can use following `VBA` function

```
Function DateTimeConversion(strDT As String) As Date
Dim MyDate As Date
    
    MyDate = DateSerial(Right(strDT, 4), Left(Right(strDT, 6), 2), Left(Right(strDT, 8), 2)) + TimeSerial(Left(strDT, 2), 0, 0)

DateTimeConversion = MyDate
End Function
```

Then call that function from `Command Button` or use `Update` query.

```
Private Sub cmdConvertDateTime()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")

rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        rs.Edit
        rs!ConvertedDateTime = DateTimeConversion(rs!SampleID)
        rs.Update
       rs.MoveNext
    Loop

Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]